# Issues With Persistent React Native Login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am trying to make a persistent login system with React Native and expo but am running into several issues. I read online that `AsyncStorage` is the way to do this. I wrote three functions for dealing with login, all seen below.

```js
// use asyncstorage to log in the user
logInUser = async (uid) => await AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedin', uid)

// set loggedin to null in asyncstorage
logOutUser = async() => await AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedin', null)

// returns userid if user is logged in
getUserState = async() => await AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedin')
```

On my login screen, I use the following `onPress` event to log in the user.

```js
onPress={() => {
    db.logInUser(this.user[1]).then(() => {
        //this.removekey(this.user[1]) // delete the user's one-time-login key
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') // navigate to home
    })
}}
```

Also on the login screen, I use the following `componentDidMount` function to send the user to the homescreen if they are already logged in.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    db.getUserState().then(loggedin => {
        if (loggedin != null) { // log the user in if they have a uid in asyncstorage
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
    })
}
```

The app will not have a "logout" feature, and users should stay logged in until either buying a new phone or reinstalling the app. Unfortunately this code does not work, and actually automatically logs the user in. I was thinking that it could maybe relate to the user with `id=0`, but removing this user from the database had no effect. The code of the actual application is [here](https://github.com/mohigancs/MHS-Protect).

Comment: i didn't get it. you said there is no logout. so only first time you launch app `loggedin` is not set and after first login it will never be null. so app must login every other time 'cause `loggedin` isn't null.

Comment: @Amas that is how it is intended to work, but it is not working that way. The app does not even ask the user to log in on the first time they launch it (it skips right to the homescreen).

Comment: the codes seems correct. did you console.log `loggedin` to see whether its set nor not?

Comment: @Amas yes I did and whenever you launch the app for the first time it console logs the `uid` of the first user in the database (1) instead of `null`